# Printing Files silently without opening them

Tags: c#, file, printing, process, processstartinfo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET: How to print files w/o opening them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018137/net-how-to-print-files-w-o-opening-them)

I want to print my files discreetly without opening them 
I've been told to do this :

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(documentFileName);
psi.Verb = "Print";
Process.Start(psi);
```

but ProcessStartInfo open the given file so how can I do my printing silently ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018137/net-how-to-print-files-w-o-opening-them may be useful.

Comment: @Slaks I should be applying this to any kind of file

Comment: so if I'm not conerned with the extension of 'documentFileName' (well in the matter of fact I'm handeling a list of files and I need to print them whatever their type was) what other alternative I should be doing instead of sending them to ProcessStartInfo ??

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Comment: no Hidden mode is not the same as a silent mode, Hidden mode will open the file but won't show it which I'm avoiding to do !

Answer (score 0):

try using PrintDocument Class check the link below

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28VS.80%29.aspx